# Find h3 and h4 tags beneath it

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

This is my HTML:

```
<h3>test 1</h3>
<p>blah</p>
<h4>subheading 1</h4>
<p>blah</p>
<h4>subheading 2</h4>
<h3>test 2</h3>
<h4>subheading 3</h4>
<p>blah</p>
<h3>test 3</h3>
```

I am trying to build an array of the h3 tags, with the h4 tags nested within them. An example of the array would look like:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [0] => subheading 1
            [1] => subheading 2
        )

    [test 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => subheading 3
        )

    [test 3] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Happy to use preg_match or DOMDocument, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With DOMDocument:

- use XPath `"//h3"` to find all `<h3>`. These will be the first-level entries in your array
- for each of them:

  - count a variable `$i` (count from 1!) as part of the loop
  - use XPath `"./following::h4[count(preceding::h3) = $i]"` to find any sub-ordinate `<h4>`
  - these will be second-level in you array

The XPath expression is "select all `<h4>` that have a the same constant number of  preceding `<h3>`". For the first `<h3>` that count is 1, naturally, for the second the count is 2, and so on.

Be sure to execute the XPath expression in the context of the respective `<h3>` nodes.